# Screen duplication makes it impossible to select native resolution in fullscreen games

Tags: windows-10, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a 1440p monitor connected via Displayport and a 1080p monitor connected via HDMI to a Nvidia GPU.

When I duplicate the 1440p screen to the 1080p screen I am unable to select resolutions higher than 1080p in fullscreen games. (Windowed games and other programs still display in 1440p)

I tried creating a virtual resolution of 1440p for the 1080p screen and I verified that the resolution is actually in the registry, but that didn't solve the issue.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get the full Resolution is by using a Monitor to tower type of connection. For some Reason HDMI cannot duplicate the Correct Resolution coming from the Parent or it doesn't have the compatibility.